# How to detect when calling 'drop' is needed for a type?

Tags: memory-management, rust

When types such as `Vec` run `truncate`, they call `ptr::drop_in_place` on every member of the vector.

This turns out not to be a performance problem for primitive types such as int's, float's etc... because the drop calls are optimized out.

For more involved container types (ones I've written for my own use), iterating over elements may not be so trivial *(and may not always get optimized away)*.

Is there a way to check if a type has a drop trait so visiting all members can be avoided in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::needs_drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.needs_drop.html).

As per the description, this function is safe, and therefore not calling the destructor should be sound.

#### Prior to 1.21.0

The [`std::intrinsics::needs_drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.needs_drop.html) could be used, though requiring a (perma-unstable) feature to be activated.

It is still usable, and still unstable.

Comment: The description in the documentation that you linked to seems to imply that: all types either _require drop glue_ or  _implement Copy_, but never both. This doesn't sound right.

Comment: @PeterHall It does not imply that all types do one of these things, and in fact explicitly mentions types which are neither. But is indeed true that being `Copy` is mutually exclusive with having drop glue -- types which are themselves `Drop` or contain things that are `Drop` (the criteria for having drop glue) can never be `Copy`.

Comment: Note that `Vec::truncate()` does not need to check `needs_drop()`, because it just creates a slice and drops it. The compiler automatically does nothing for dropping a slice. Only if you have an explicit loop dropping you may need to check this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reason about `Drop` in generic bounds. Types which don't have an explicit `Drop` impl, don't fulfill a `Drop` bound:

```
fn foo<T: Drop>(t: T) {}

foo(5);
foo("5".to_owned());
```

Only types with an explicit `Drop` impl fulfill this bound:

```
foo(vec![42]); // works
```

`Drop` is silently handled by the compiler in the background (otherwise you'd have to specify it everywhere). This means, that not even specialization or OIBITs can be used as a workaround.

That said, you can detect whether any (even a generated) drop impl exists (but you shouldn't) by turning a value of the type into a trait object and checking whether the vtable's drop entry is `NULL` or not.

Comment: It's not quite true that "no type actually fulfills a `Drop` bound" (for example, `Vec<T>` does, as of Rust 1.15.1), but you're right that using a `Drop` bound is not the correct way to detect a type that has a destructor/drop glue.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Gotta read up on that, thanks for the hint.

Comment: oh... it's any type with an explicit drop impl that fulfills the bound.